# how to maintain the checkbox state after navigating from one ViewController to another ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

i have a table view and i places button on a tableview as a checkbox ,now i want to maintain state of checkbox's .my problem is when i am navigate from one view controller to another OR  terminating my application all checkbox's are unchecked which was previously checked. any suggestion appreciable.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"identfier%d",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:str];

    UILabel *lblValue;
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:str];

        lblValue=[[UILabel alloc]init ];

        lblValue.tag=indexPath.row+20000;
        btnValue=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        btnValue.tag=indexPath.row+100;
    }else{
       lblValue=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+20000];
       btnValue=(UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+100];

    }

    lblValue.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblValue.text=[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"CategoryName"];
    //lblValue.text=@"some value";

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radiou.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImage1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioc.png"];
    [btnValue setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnValue setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateSelected];


    [btnValue addTarget:self action:@selector(checkedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnValue.frame=CGRectMake(10, 15, 25, 25);

    if([self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title isEqual:@"Done"]){
        [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            lblValue.frame=CGRectMake(35+25, 17, 200, 20);
           btnValue.hidden=NO;

        } completion:nil];  
    }
    else
    {
        [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
             lblValue.frame=CGRectMake(35, 17, 200, 20);

            btnValue.hidden=YES;
        } completion:nil];

    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnValue];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblValue];

    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: You should restore button checked state in cellForRowAtIndexPath  because after reloading the table buttons become deselected by default. Therefore you need a data structure to store button states.

Comment: @vokilam sorry but i want to main state after termination of my application

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can make a NSArray containing check box's values. Now when viewWillDissappear is called, you can save this array in NSUserDefaults and on viewWillAppear, you can retrieve the array and from NSUserDefaults and set values in checkboxes accordingly.

Suppose you have 10 rows in your table, then you can make an array with count as 10. Now if 4th and 5th row's checkbox is selected, then you can put 1 at index 3 and 4 and rest of the indexes should be 0.

```
int arrayCount = 10;//enter number of rows you have

NSMutableArray *checkStatusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<arrayCount; i++)
{
 if([[checkBoxStatusArray objectAtIndex: i]integerValue] == 1)
 // Above mentioned array should be made prior to this method from which checkbox will be loaded or you can make 0 entries here for every indexInitially
 {
  [checkStatusArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
 }
 else
 {
  [checkStatusArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"]];
 }
}
// To put value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:checkStatusArray forKey:@"statusArray"];

// Now to fetch value
NSArray *valuesArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey: @"statusArray"];
```

Comment: Note: `viewDidUnload` is deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.

Comment: you mean through tagging i have to store checkbox's values

Comment: @Ashutosh-Systematix if u have time can u write some logic for this.

Comment: check edit, and I have just typed the code here itself so please solve formatting errors if occur.

Comment: this array is to be made in viewdidload with 0 at every index and should be updated after each action for checkbox ie. if check box at index 2 is selected, then array's 2nd index should become 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep state in your viewControllers without saving and loading state to persistent storage, you should make your viewControllers properties of their parentViewControllers.

That way they won't be deallocated when you navigate away from them.

You must also remember to only alloc and init them once.

Comment: i want make like setting one time selected and it remain all time..?

Comment: do you mean, even when the application is terminated?

Comment: In that case you'll have to use NSUserDefaults Or implement the NSCoding protocol